# Remove HTML tag based on it's content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I remove an HTML tag, depending on what the content is?

For example:

```html
<header>
 <h3>
  <a href="/category/people/">People</a>
  <a href="/category/hide/">Hide</a>
  <a href="/category/also-hide/">Also Hide</a>
 </h3>
</header>
```

How can I remove an `<a>` tag, if the content equals "Hide" and "Also Hide"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector:

```
$( "a:contains('Hide')" ).remove();
```

Comment: might want to switch from div to anchor tag

Answer (score 1):

Another way is with CSS, using pseudo elements.

Technically this only hides the element though, so based on whether they are to be easily visible again this might be an option.

```css
a:after {
  content: attr(data-value);
}

a[data-value~="Hide"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
 <h3>
  <a href="/category/people/" data-value="People"></a>
  <a href="/category/hide/" data-value="Hide"></a>
  <a href="/category/also-hide/" data-value="Also Hide"></a>
 </h3>
</header>
```